# R pipe does not stop when triggering error

Tags: r, magrittr

I've created this demo pipeline:

```
library(magrittr)
fun1 <- function(x) {
  cat("hello1")
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  stop("stop %>% here!")
}

fun3 <- function(x) {
  cat("hello3")
}

5 %>% fun1() %>% fun2() %>% fun3()

> `hello3`
```

I'm quite confused about two things:

a) why only `hello3` is printed and not `hello1`?

b) what is even more confusing is that fact that even `fun2()` produces an error, `fun3` will still be called. I thought that `stop` in R triggers an execution error and without any catching mechanism this is going to produce the stop of the script.

Could someone explain me why this seems not to hold when using `%>%`. How can I ensure that the pipe stops if some function call produces an error?

Comment: `5 %>% fun1() %>% fun2() %>% fun3()` is another form of writing: `fun3(fun2(fun1(5)))`. And `fun3()` does only one thing (`cat("hello3")` independently of the its input `x`.

Answer (score 4):

`fun2()` (and `fun1()`) are not called because `x` argument of `fun3()` is not used in the function and thus not evaluated. Try rewriting that pipeline with nested calls:

```r
library(magrittr)
fun1 <- function(x) {
  cat("hello1")
}

fun2 <- function(x) {
  stop("stop %>% here!")
}

fun3 <- function(x) {
  cat("hello3")
}

# -------------------------------------------------------------------------

fun1(5)
#> hello1

fun2(fun1(5))
#> Error in fun2(fun1(5)): stop %>% here!

fun3(fun2(fun1(5)))
#> hello3
```

And now, let's put argument `x` into some use and try again:

```r
fun3x <- function(x) {
  cat("hello3",x)
}

5 %>% fun1() %>% fun2() %>% fun3x()
#> Error in fun2(.): stop %>% here!
```

---

You might also want to check [lazy evaluation](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functions.html#lazy-evaluation) in the functions chapter of Advanced R

> In R, function arguments are lazily evaluated: they’re only evaluated if accessed.